# How to pass weights in lm object as a variable from outside the function and refer the column name as weight in the model form?

Tags: r, lm

I have a function to create lm object for multiple model iterations and the weights are an input to the function, which take different column values.

Here is the dummy:

```
x <-c(rnorm(10),NA)
df <- data.frame(y=1+2*x+rnorm(11)/2, x=x, wght1=1:11)

## Fancy weights as numeric vector

df$weight <- (df$wght1)^(3/4)
weight_var <- "weight"

model <-  lm(y~x,data=df,weights=df[, weight_var])

model$call[[4]]
```

See, the `model$call[[4]]` returns `df[, weight_var]`, I'd want it to return the column `weight` instead; which is the reference to that variable

Say I have columns a, b, c, d, e in the data, I want to run the model and check for weights possibility being d or e.

Thus, I define the if statement as this:

```
if (weight_var[[1]]=='') {
    model <- lm(formula = eqmodel, xdata)
  } else {
    model <- lm(formula = eqmodel, xdata, weights = xdata[,weight_var])
  }
```

where `weight_var` can be `d` or `e`. So that when we call:

```
model$call[[4]]
```

the output is either `d` or `e`.

However, when I see the model as:

```
Call:
lm(formula = eqmodel, data = xdata, weights = xdata[, weight_var])
```

I am okay with the eqmodel being equation of the model being specified from outside the function. However, I would like the weights to be d or e as it was passed. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Your question seems very theoretical and thus becomes even harder to answer without any working data. Also, in your `if...else` statement, you seem to have missed the `if` call?

Comment: Updated, a dummy dataframe and code. Please let me know if more details are needed

Comment: what about `model$weights` ?

Comment: It gives the value of the weights and not the column name

Comment: Use bquote to compute on the language and then eval.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

model$call[[i]] returns the values of lm() parameters letter by letter, so not only model$call[[4]] looks uninformative, but also model$call[[2]] returns the name of formula instead of the formula. Below a trick to improve it a little bit.

```
x <-c(rnorm(10),NA)
df <- data.frame(y=1+2*x+rnorm(11)/2, x=x, wght1=1:11)

## Fancy weights as numeric vector

df$weight <- (df$wght1)^(3/4)
weight_var <- "weight"
eqmodel <- as.formula("y~x")
xdata <- df

### unprocessed:
if (weight_var[[1]]=='') {
  model <- lm(formula = eqmodel, xdata)
} else {
  model <- lm(formula = eqmodel, xdata, weights = xdata[,weight_var])
}
summary(model)
#Call:
#lm(formula = eqmodel, data = xdata, weights = xdata[, weight_var])

### a little trick:
if (weight_var[[1]]=='') {
  model <- lm(formula = eqmodel, xdata)
} else {
  model <- lm(formula = eqmodel, xdata, weights = xdata[,weight_var])
  model$call[[4]] <- weight_var[[1]]
}
model$call[[2]] <- eqmodel
summary(model)

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x, data = xdata, weights = "weight")
```

Comment: For my purpose, I want model$call[[4]] to return the name of the column that was used as weights. It is imperative